# Ubuntu 13.10 : error mounting /export/video1 on boot

Tags: boot, error-handling

Ubuntu 13.10 installed on Acer C720 Chromebook (after unscrewing write-protect screw and enabling SeaBIOS boot).  Everything works OK *except* on boot, I get this message on the Ubuntu splash screen:

```
An error occurred while mounting /export/video1.
Press S to skip mountin or M for manual recovery.
```

so I have to press a key to continue the boot (no remote restart). The funny thing is, this device has only one video camera, built into the screen, which is /dev/video0 and which works OK after boot. 'dmesg' has no mention of this mysterious video1 device, how can I debug this?  Some info:

```
user@C720:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASMedia 2105 SATA bridge
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:8110  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 2222:3085 MacAlly 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b95:7720 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0489:e056 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c67 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:2811  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
user@C720:~$ uname -a
Linux C720 3.11.0-26-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, this was all my fault. /export/video1 is just an entry in my /etc/fstab file which I had copied from a different setup, which had a hard drive that this one doesn't have. I commented out that entry, and that fixed the problem on next boot.